# Laravel to Pure PHP conversion - PHP Flutter Upload Multiple Images to database

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, image-upload

I want to convert this Laravel code into pure php. I am trying to upload multiple images using image picker package. My frontend is in flutter and backend is in php. For uploading images to the database, I want some help with this. I got Laravel code as reference. I want to convert it into simple PHP.

[Code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUnhI.png)

Updates : I was trying to upload multiple images to database. I solved the same using following code.

```
class AddFlatGallery extends StatefulWidget {
const AddFlatGallery({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
State<AddFlatGallery> createState() => _AddFlatGalleryState();
}

class _AddFlatGalleryState extends State<AddFlatGallery> {
String flatname = '';
String buildingname = '';
String flatlocation = '';
Future CheckFlat() async {
SharedPreferences preferencesaddflat =
    await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
setState(() {
  flatname = preferencesaddflat.getString('flatname') ?? "Not 
found";
  buildingname =
      preferencesaddflat.getString('buildingname') ?? "Not 
found";
  flatlocation =
      preferencesaddflat.getString('flatlocation') ?? "Not 
found";
 
});

}

late List<Asset> images = [];
Dio dio = Dio();

Widget buildGridView() {
return GridView.count(
    crossAxisCount: 3,
    crossAxisSpacing: 7,
    children: List.generate(images.length, (index) {
      Asset asset = images[index];
      return AssetThumb(
        asset: asset,
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
      );
    }));
 }

 Future<void> loadAssets() async {
 List<Asset> resultList = [];

 try {
  resultList = await MultiImagePicker.pickImages(
      maxImages: 300,
      enableCamera: true,
      selectedAssets: images,
      cupertinoOptions: const CupertinoOptions(takePhotoIcon: 
 "chat"),
      materialOptions: const MaterialOptions(
        actionBarColor: "#abcdef",
        actionBarTitle: "TenantPay",
        allViewTitle: "All Photos",
        useDetailsView: false,
        selectCircleStrokeColor: "#000000",
      ));
  } on Exception catch (e) {
  print(e.toString());
  }
  if (!mounted) return;

  if (mounted) {
  setState(() {
    images = resultList;
  });
  }
  }

  final Timer _timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 
  5), ((timer) {}));

  @override
  void dispose() {
 super.dispose();
  _timer.cancel(); //cancel the timer here
  }

 _saveImage() async {
 if (images != null) {
  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    ByteData byteData = await images[i].getByteData();
    List<int> imageData = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();

    MultipartFile multipartFile = 
   MultipartFile.fromBytes(imageData,
        filename: images[i].name, contentType: 
   MediaType('image', 'jpg'));

    FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
      "image": multipartFile,
      "flat": flatname,
      "building": buildingname,
      "location": flatlocation,
    });

    

    var response =
        await dio.post(ApiConstant.flatuploadurl, data: 
     formData);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(response.data);

      
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: "Images are added successfully",
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
          gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
          timeInSecForIosWeb: 3,
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 16.0);
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => const Home(),
        ),
      );
      
      }
     }
     }
    }

  @override
  void initState() {
  super.initState();
  CheckFlat();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 30, 64, 122),
    title: const Text(
      'Upload Images',
    ),
  ),
  body: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            loadAssets();
          },
          child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
        Expanded(child: buildGridView()),
        Container(
          height: 60,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),
          child: CustomButton(
            text: 'Save',
            color: Colors.orange,
            onTap: () {
              _saveImage();
            },
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          height: 60,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),
          child: CustomButton(
            text: 'Continue without adding Images',
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => const Home(),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

Comment: How is this a Flutter question?  Removing tag.

Answer (score 0):

you can just handle it like that with a foreach around. Thats a Basic Tutorial.

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

And also there is no Laravel to PHP convert